# Generating link preview and detect video/image using a URL!

Tags: html, image, url, video, preview

I am getting the HTML content of the page using the URL. once i got the HTML i m striping all the images using Xpath. I m stuck at how to fetch the video content. If i try checking for embed code ,it gives me all the adds inside the page. Please suggest me a workaround. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something yql to solve this problem.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_javascript